# Localized estimate for divergence free vector field

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, potential-theory

Suppose $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is a simply connected Lipchitz domain. For a divergence free field $w\in [L^2(\Omega)]^d$, it is well known that there exists a vector field $v\in [W^{1,2}(\Omega)]^{d}$ with $\nabla v \in [L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)]^{d\times d}$ such that
$w = \text{curl }v$, the following estimates exists:
$$
\|v\|_{H^1(\Omega)} \leq C \|w\|_{L^2(\Omega)}.
$$

On any Lipschitz sub-region $\omega \subset \Omega$, I wonder whether we still have the same type estimate for the above $v$ and $w$:
$$
\|v\|_{H^1(\omega)} \leq C' \|w\|_{L^2(\omega)},
$$
where $C'$ is independent of $\omega$ but could depend on $\Omega$.

Comment: You should take look at "Potential operators" and "Bogovskii operators". See for instance the paper **arXiv:0808.2614** by Costabel and McIntosh.